# Rules-of-thumb doc for mathematical programming in R?

Tags: r, numerical-analysis

Does there exist a simple, cheatsheet-like document which compiles the best practices for mathematical computing in R? Does anyone have a short list of their best-practices? E.g., it would include items like:

1. For large numerical vectors `x`, instead of computing `x^2`, one should compute `x*x`. This speeds up calculations.
2. To solve a system $Ax = b$, never solve $A^{-1}$ and left-multiply $b$. Lower order algorithms exist (e.g., Gaussian elimination)

I did find a nice numerical analysis cheatsheet [here](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cs421-cheat-sheet4.pdf). But I'm looking for something quicker, dirtier, and more specific to R.

Comment: ad 1 - I tried it and - really! Good trick, new for me! :-)

Comment: The short list would be useless because it's a huge topic. Also, this site is for specific problems. Question doesn't fit. Please read [faq].

Comment: This is too open ended, and can range from the trivial to the complex.

Comment: Question was upvoted by 3 people and favorited by 2, so it is definitely interesting may it fit or not. We are programmers but just PEOPLE, not FAQ-directed machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dirk Eddelbeuttel has posted a bunch of stuff on "high performance computing with R". He's also a regular so will probably come along and grab some well-deserved reputation points. While you are waiting you can read some of his stuff here: 
http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/ismNov2009introHPCwithR.pdf

There is an archive of the r-devel mailing list where discussions about numerical analysis issues relating to R performance occur. I will often put its URL in the Google advanced search page domain slot when I want to see what might have been said in the past: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/

Comment: He is maintainer of the HOC task view on CRAN.  That and the slides are a good starting point.

Comment: Very useful stuff. Definitely close to what I'm looking for. I may just start my own "rules-of-thumb" document as an abridged version of what's found from your links. I'm sure that could be helpful to a number of people.